# Using PyMySQL, I can't connect to RDS

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services, rds, pymysql

Using `PyMySQL`, I get `pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1045, u"Access denied for user 'my_user'@'<MY_IP_ADDRESS>' (using password: YES)")`, however, I can login from the command line or MySQL Workbench using the same credentials on this machine. And, I can connect to `localhost` using PyMySQL. Here's my sample test code:

```
import pymysql
prod_conn = pymysql.connect(
  host='correct-host-name.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com',
  user='my_user',
  password='correct_password',
  port=3306,
  database='my_db')
```

However, using `mysql -hcorrect-host-name.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com -umy_user -pcorrect_password -P3306 -Dmy_db` from the command line on the same machine, I get in just fine.

After Googling, I tried checking the grants for the user and I *believe* that the user is setup correctly. `SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER()` returns

```
Grants for my_user@%
'GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD, PROCESS, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE USER, EVENT, TRIGGER ON *.* TO \'my_user\'@\'%\' WITH GRANT OPTION'
```

I tried checking `SELECT USER(), CURRENT_USER();` and get back

```
USER()                      CURRENT_USER()
'my_user@<MY_IP_ADDRESS>'   'my_user@%'
```

So, it seems that the user is setup properly, which I suspected since I can connect through other options. I also tried both suggestions from https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=707103 (specifically, using a different parameter group with `log_bin_trust_function_creators == 1` and using a password without punctuation) to no avail.

I want to use this in a lambda function, so I really want to use PyMySQL to keep this a python only solution rather than trying MySQLDB or another library.

I don't think there are any anonymous users after reviewing `SELECT user,host FROM mysql.user;`

```
user        host
'my_user'   '%'
'mysql.sys' 'localhost'
'rdsadmin'  'localhost'
```

Appreciate any other thoughts this community might have on how to proceed...

Comment: Can you try running `SHOW GRANTS FOR USER()` and report back?

Comment: Is it possible that instead   password='correct_password', you need to use 'passwd=correct_password' ?

Comment: @BrianDriscoll `SHOW GRANTS FOR USER();` is an invalid statement (according to MySQL Workbench). `SHOW GRANTS FOR my_user;` gives the same response as `SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER();`

Comment: @olegsv this is a kwarg, so it _should_ be as entered in the question. See https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/master/example.py#L6 for an example

Comment: @jcasner in the example it's 'passwd', in your code ut's 'password'.

Comment: @olegsv either works (or should work) -
 see https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/master/pymysql/connections.py#L572. Also, the error message indicates it is using the password (`(using password: YES)`). If I don't include either `passwd` or `password`, the error is has `(using password: NO)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by creating a new user. I only needed read privileges for this user, so it's a better approach than using the default user with such high permissions. I'm still not sure why the original one didn't work, but here's what ended up working:

```
# Grants for my_new_user@%
'GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO \'my_new_user\'@\'%\''
```